# Django multiple URL parameters that are agnostic to their order in the URL

Tags: python, regex, django, django-rest-framework

I'm building an API which queries a database based on multiple URL filters. In this example there are two parameters which I would like to pass to my views: `<tid>` and `<teams>`. Note that in production there would be over 5 different parameters, so I'm trying to avoid brute force solutions.

My intended approach was the following regular expression in `urls.py`

```
url(r'(?P<teams>-?teams=[0-9]*)?(?P<tournaments>-?tid=[0-9]*)?',
    stats_views.game_query, name='stats_home')
```

This RE successfully matches and passes any URL which is of the form `/teams=####-tid=####`, and both the `teams=` and the `tid=` parameters are optional (this is intended). The problem is that `tid=` always has to come AFTER the `teams=` part of the URL. For example if I were to enter the URL `/tid=###-teams=###`, the `<tid>` parameter would be passed to views with its intended value, but the `<teams>` parameter would be passed as `None`.

Comment: Try `r'(?:(?P<teams>-?teams=[0-9]*)(?:(?P<tournaments>-?tid=[0-9]*)?)?)?'`. Although, I feel the `teams` part should be required, [`(?P<teams>-?teams=[0-9]*)(?:(?P<tournaments>-?tid=[0-9]*)?)?`](https://regex101.com/r/Akqzcs/1)

Comment: Same outcome as before; matches only when `teams=` preceeds `tid=` @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Well, you yourself wrote *The problem is that tid= always has to come AFTER the teams= part of the URL.* If it has to come after `teams`, then `tid` cannot be before it.

Comment: Maybe my wording is misleading: I want order not to matter (i.e. order agnostic parameters). Hence the mandatory order is the problem. Otherwise the original RegEx works. In any case I think my initial approach was fundamentally mistaken and the accepted answer proposed a much cleaner implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To propose an alternate solution that might be more easily followed and avoid this dance, perhaps consider using query strings. Order agnostic and [fully supported in DRF](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-query-parameters).